# checking if a very large number is divisible by 2 comes wrong

Tags: python, long-integer, division, collatz

I am trying some stuff on the 3x+1 problem and noticed when I check if this num is divisible by two comes always true even that the second iteration should be false it goes like this for 20 iterations and then start to act right. I guess it is a long number issue?

```
num = 3656565605161651626526625291991265161656

while num != 1:
    if (num % 2 == 0):
        num /= 2
        print("2")
    else:
        num *= 3
        num += 1
        print("3")
    num2=f'{num:.1f}'
    print(num2)
```

Here is the start of the result:

```
2
1828282802580825918440824287108404346880
2
914141401290412959220412143554202173440
2
457070700645206479610206071777101086720
2
```

Comment: In Python 3, `num /= 2` is float division, even if both sides are integer; try `num //= 2`

Comment: Why should the second iteration be `False`? 3656565605161651626526625291991265161656/2 is 1828282802580825918440824287108404346880, which is still divisible by 2.

Comment: so its not the check its the division going wrong... since the result doesn't make sense

Comment: I don't get this output, neither with Python 3 that yields a float after the first division, nor with Python 2 that gives integers (and correct values different from the ones in your output) . Please provide the output matching your code.

Comment: -Thierry Lathuille can you try the code after editing plz

Answer (score 1):

You need to use integer division, not float.

```
        num //= 2
```

Here are the first 20 lines of the output, where you can see it is working:

```
2
1828282802580825813263312645995632580828
2
914141401290412906631656322997816290414
2
457070700645206453315828161498908145207
3
1371212101935619359947484484496724435622
2
685606050967809679973742242248362217811
3
2056818152903429039921226726745086653434
2
1028409076451714519960613363372543326717
3
3085227229355143559881840090117629980152
2
1542613614677571779940920045058814990076
2
771306807338785889970460022529407495038
```

Comment: i did but its still not working

Comment: Then you typed it wrong.  I ran your code here with that one-character change and it works correctly.

Comment: i am getting the same result with an extra 0 at the end ?? how are you displaying the numbers ?

Comment: thank you its working now guess the way i was displaying it was the mistake